# How to minimize reducers boilerplate when using redux with a POJO state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I face difficulties to write reducers for Redux. Specifically I end up wrapping a lot of my state manipulation  in .map, .slice etc. When the structure of my state object grows larger, the reducers become hard to read, with functions wrapping functions etc.

- I didn't want to use Immutable.js as I wanted to stick to simple POJO as long as possible
- I tried using [combineReducers](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/combineReducers.html) and [reduceReducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) libs, with are awesome. But often I end up requiring a large chunk of the state in my reducer.
- I wrote a little utility, to help with creating a new state:

```js
var path = require('immutable-path').path;

let state = {
            level1: {
                level21: {
                    level3: 3
                },
                level22: [{
                    id: 1,
                    val: 1
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    val: 2
                }]
            }
        };


  let newState = path(state, 'level1.level22[id=1].val', x => x + 10);
```

It gives a new state, leaving the original state the same. The references of objects and arrays not modified stay the same (=== comparison is true).

Can someone tells me if I'm missing an easier way with es6 syntax to perform the same results? Or another better community maintained lib to get the same benefits?

Thanks for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking your reducer up into smaller functions.

Below are four functions, each in turn deals with a smaller part of the state. (Though in each case the first parameter is called state, it's different every time). The action though, is always the same.

I haven't checked this code for correctness, but I hope you get the idea.

```
function reducerTop(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VAL:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                [action.topLevel]: reducerNext(state[action.topLevel], action);
            });
    }
    return state;
}

function reducerNext(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VAL:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                [action.nextLevel]: reducerArray(state[action.nextLevel], action);
            });
    }
    return state;
}

function reducerArray(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VAL:
            const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.id);
            if (index > -1) {
                return [
                    ...state.slice(0, index),
                    reducerFinal(state[index], action),
                    ...state.slice(index + 1)
                ];
            }
    }
    return state;
}

function reducerFinal(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VAL:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                value: action.value
            });
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid this kind of code, but it has the advantage of reducing the number of reducers to go through for a given action.

Comment: I now release there was massive oversight in my original example code. I forgot to retain the parts of the state not being worked on. I've now corrected that with the use of Object.assign and Array slicing/spreading.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of redux itself -- it is just too low-level, and some things (like nested updates, for instance), just should be easier. Also, I believe that there is no problems to put all business logic into action creators, and inside reducers just update our state (and to perform nested updates, if needed).

Another unnecessary thing, from my point of view -- constants. We usually have some object with all redux entities (for instance, reducers), and I think it should be enough to figure out all needed constants.

With this thoughts, I wrote a library [redux-tiles](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles), which does exactly that -- based on given type, it creates constants, handles async functions, and creates reducers for you. So, typical API request will look like the following:

```
import { createTile } from 'redux-tiles';
const requestTile = createTile({
  type: ['api', 'request'],
  fn: ({ api, params }) => api.get('/items', params),
});
```

It will create all constants, a reducer, and also handle failure, success and loading states. You can take a look at the full HN API example with redux-tiles [here](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles/blob/master/examples/hacker-news-api/hn-tiles.js). You might find there nesting, which will update everything automatically, you just need to return an array of values to nest.